# React: XMLHttpRequest devuelve un error 404 y el archivo existe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, http-post, xmlhttprequest

Estaba trabajando en una app de React cuando el problema ocurrió. Estaba trabajando con `XMLHttpRequest` para insertar nueva información en un archivo JSON (con el método `POST`) pero el server respondió con un status 404. Algunas cositas que quiero mencionar:

1. Mi archivo JSON (llamado "Data.json") está en la carpeta "public" de React.
2. Mi app no está hosteada por ahora, asi que la inicié con "npm start" en un localhost.
3. Verifiqué que la ruta sea correcta, asi que hay un archivo JSON ahí.
4. La petición es llamada cuando el usuario clickea un botón, asi que esto ocurre cuando la app está totalmente iniciada.
5. La función está llamada correctamente, asi que no es un problema del event listener.

**Error:**

```
POST http://localhost:3000/Data.json 404 (Not Found)
```

**Javascript:**

```
async function download() {

    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
    let url = "/Data.json"
    let obj = {
        "unlockedChars":API.unlockedChars,
        "completed":API.completed,
        "lastCompleted":API.lastCompleted
    }
    
    
    xhr.open("POST", url)
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify(obj))
}
```

**Data.json:**

```
[{
"unlockedChars":[{
    "id":"Ancient_One",
    "star":2,
    "duplicated":false
},
{
    "id":"Ancient_One",
    "star":3,
    "duplicated":true
}],
"completed":0,
"lastCompleted":0
}]
```

Comment: Estas en StackOverflow en Español.

Comment: Me di cuenta tarde jajaja

Comment: Ahora traduzco todo

Comment: No le puedes hacer una peticion POST a un archivo estatico. Para hacer lo que quieres necesitas crear un proyecto aparte con logica de backend.

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias